# How to deploy and run EAR java Program with out Web Interface?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, websphere, ear

HI I am trying to develop an application (EAR) to deploy it on WebSphere application server.

The goal is after deployment, the program needs to run automatically. There is no Web UI required, how do I achieve that? Below is the code. Its just a simple consumer that listens to kafka topic and prints messages.

//Create java class named "SimpleProducer”
public class SimpleConsumer{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    /*
     * // Check arguments length value if(args.length == 0){
     * System.out.println("Enter topic name"); return; }
     */
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleConsumer.class);

    // Assign topicName to string variable
    String topicName = "first_topic";

    // create instance for properties to access producer configs
    Properties props = new Properties();

    // Assign localhost id
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka165.harishfysx.com:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG , StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-fourth-applicaiton");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG , "earliest");



    // Create Consumer
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    // Subscribe
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(topicName));
    //Poll data

    
    while(true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record :  records) {
            logger.info( "Value :" + record.value());
            logger.info("Offset :" + record.offset());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can create singleton startup bean - see this - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gippq/index.html and deploy your application as EJB jar module in WebSphere, or EAR that contains just ejb jar, without any web ui (war).